# Can't see the bottom of screen when using an ion-segment in the screen

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using the `ion-grid` / `ion-row` / `ion-col` to define a form and it works fine. On the top of this form, I'm also using an `ion-segment` to implement some tabs:

```
<ion-header no-border>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title class="home-toolbar-background">Mes sports</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <div padding *ngIf="items && items.length > 0">
    <ion-segment text-center [(ngModel)]="item" 
                 (ngModelChange)="onItemChange($event)">
      <ion-segment-button value="item1" *ngIf="hasSport('item1')">
        Item1
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="item2" *ngIf="hasSport('item2')">
        Item2
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="item3" *ngIf="hasSport('item3')">
        Item3
      </ion-segment-button>
      (...)
    </ion-segment>
  </div>

  <ion-grid>
    ...
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

It works fine within the browser in development mode but, in IonicView, I can't reach the end of the form by scrolling. It seems the height of the screen is calculated without the height of the tabs block.

Note that this screen is part of

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="pricetag" tabTitle="Tab1" [root]="tab1"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="calendar" tabTitle="Tab2" [root]="tab2"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="walk" tabTitle="Items" [root]="tabItems"></ion-tab> <--------------
  <ion-tab tabIcon="person" tabTitle="Tab3" [root]="tab3"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab tabIcon="chatboxes" tabTitle="Notifs" [root]="tabNotifications"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Could you please create a Stackblitz project with the issue? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too faced similar issue and it might look silly but it does the trick.

At the end of your ion-content your `<div padding></div>`

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div padding *ngIf="items && items.length > 0">
    <ion-segment text-center [(ngModel)]="item" 
                 (ngModelChange)="onItemChange($event)">
      <ion-segment-button value="item1" *ngIf="hasSport('item1')">
        Item1
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="item2" *ngIf="hasSport('item2')">
        Item2
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="item3" *ngIf="hasSport('item3')">
        Item3
      </ion-segment-button>
      (...)
    </ion-segment>
  </div>

  <ion-grid>
    ...
  </ion-grid>

<div padding></div>
<div padding></div>
</ion-content>
```

What happens is `.scroll-content` is been occupied till the bottom of the screen.
and tabs are placed above the `.scroll-content` NOTE: tabs are not a part of the respected Screen.thats why we are faceing this issue will solve just by bottom of the screen upto the tabs `min-height:58px` will solve it